# python - open url and retrieve changed url

Tags: python, url, urllib

I want to call a url for e.g. - www.xyz.com

its a authentication url after clicking on which produce new url on url bar e.g. www.xyz-11.com

how can retrieve this from python?
to call a url and to get the newly created url?

Comment: What library are you trying to use? `urllib2`? `httplib`? Something else? Please specify more, or if you don't know what to use at all, try searching around.

Comment: i know how to call a url from python but how to retrieve new url. i dt know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> u = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
>>> dir(u)  # useful in seeing what's there, see also help(u)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__repr__', 'close', 'code', 'fileno', 'fp', 'getcode', 'geturl', 'headers', 'info', 'msg', 'next', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'url']
>>> u.geturl()
'http://www.google.com.au/'
>>> u.url
'http://www.google.com.au/'
```

See also [the documentation for `urllib2.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen);

> - `geturl()` — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to determine if a redirect was followed

Comment: Of cause this only works after HTTP redirects, many websites use `http-equiv="refresh"` or javascript redirects instead.

Comment: And if you care about those, use `BeautifulSoup` or `re` or something to detect it (I would recommend that user778942 start another question for that if he cares about that case).

Comment: yes but kindly tell me that if using python, calling geturl()  which will works only after HTTP redirect, how can i detect that?

Comment: @user778942: I'm not willing to help with that: it will be better for you to work it out yourself. Try it out and play with it yourself! (And read what what I quoted *says*.)